# For loop does not give any output in Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am very new to development and I am trying to write a little program, but I cannot seem to get this for loop working:

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args){

    double desejadaT5 = Console.userInput("What is the desejada value?");

        for (double i = desejadaT5; i <= 0; i = i * 0.367)
            System.out.println("value of i is " + i);

    }
}
```

Here is the class `Console` I created to receive the user input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Console {

    public static double userInput(String prompt){

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        double value;
        System.out.println(prompt);
        value = scanner.nextDouble();
        return value;
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this is not giving me any output? I was expecting that when I put, for example, 333 in a desejadaT5, I would get an output like: `333, 122, 44, 16, 5, 1.`

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe the condition is false from the start (If the value entered in desejadaT5 is greater than 0). If the value is greater than zero, then you probably want the condition to read  **i >= 0;** And that assumes **i = i * 0.367** will gradually decrease the value of i to 0

Comment: What is `Console`? [`System.Console`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) does not have a `userInput()` member.

Comment: What input are you trying?

Comment: Run your program and enters a value<0 e.g. -1.5 when it waits for the user input.

Comment: Just change the condition to **i >=1;**

Comment: Try `i > 0` instead.

Comment: @Kasalwe THANKS IT WORKED! Could anzone explain me why it worked with i>=1 but with i >= 0 was only printing 0? I realy dont get it...

Comment: I would kindly ask you to pay attention on your typewriting in the future. Your originak question had quite a number of simple typos, grammar and etc. errors. Just pay attention, this way you'll make it easy for others to read your question.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri im sorry if english is my third language and i made some typing errors. I will keep in mind that for the future that i need to write perfect english. I hope i didnt type any error now. And yes you deleted some of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are entering input as **333** then, your loop condition fails (**i<=0**) as 333 is not less than or equal to 0 and it throws you out of the loop

Comment: oh thanks Mr. Yash, now i understand. Thanks a lot :).

Comment: +1 but one nitpick: it does not "throw you out of the loop". The loop body is never entered as it fails the initial test.

Comment: Yes absolutely. :)